# Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity

Tags: spring, velocity

I'm new to spring and trying to use velocity with spring boot.

Here is my build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

When I sync by `./gradlew bootRun`, it returned error as below.

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity:.
```

Comment: Spring 5 dropped support for Velocity. Spring Boot depends on Spring 5 so no more Velocity support.

Comment: try to comment out `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity')` here and check if the error still appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.0 depends on Spring Framework 5.0. Which [dropped support for Velocity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods). Hence in Spring Boot 2 there is no more support for Velocity.

If you really need Velocity you would have to stick with Spring Boot 1.5. If you can move to something like Freemarker or Mustache you are probably better of using that.

Answer (score 34):

Most probably you forgot to include Spring's dependency management plugin.

`apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`

Also make sure that you have specified the Spring Boot version to use:

`plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}`

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/ for more information

Comment: @Nikerm, I updated my question.  My build.gradle has "apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'.  But still it produces same error message.

Comment: @sungyong I have updated my answer. Have you specified the spring boot version to use?

Comment: @Nikerm, I'd added "plugins {  id 'org.springframework.boot' version2.0.4.RELEASE' } at my question.  But result is same.  Where can I check?